# Как скомпилировать apk с разрешением записи во внешнее хранилище?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

IDE: Android Studio 3.0.1.
Было рабочее компилируемое приложение. Добавила создание XML-файла - в итоге перед компиляцией в манифест добавлется вот что

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Главное, что это добавляется внутри тега application (!) из-за чего компилятор ругается. Я так подозреваю, это делает Gradle. Запретила Gradle перезаписывать манифест. Перенесла uses-permission за тег application. Теперь Gradle Build ругается вот так:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'processResources' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
```

Я теперь в растерянности и не знаю что делать. Может не там (или не так) запретила перезапись манифеста?

Вот исходный код build.gradle (проекта)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.live.gdev.xprivacyappinfo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.11"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.processResources.manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    variant.processManifest.enabled=false
}
```

Манифест после преобразования

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.live.gdev.xprivacyappinfo"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.11" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="XPrivacy in App Info" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedmodule"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposedminversion"
            android:value="2.0*" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="xposeddescription"
            android:value="Adds a button to open XPrivacy for specific app to App Info page." />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: А манифест выложить можете?

Comment: Откройте манифест, переключите вид на `Merge manifest` и там может быть указано откуда добавляется этот тег. А конфликты при слиянии манифестов разрешаются при помощи специальных атрибутов. [Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html)

Comment: @V.March , выложила.